# JavaScript for-loop execution

Tags: javascript

I wrote a program to have that particular output in javascript:

> i=2 j=1
>
> i=3 j=2
>
> i=1 j=3
>
> i=2 j=1
>
> i=3 j=2
>
> i=1 j=3

and so on...

But the following code never results in the output I need.

```
c=2;
for (i=c; i<=3; i++){
    alert(i);

    if(i==1){
       j=3;
    }else{
       j=j-1;
    }

    alert(j);

    if(i==3){
        c=1;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about output prediction.

Comment: wud u at least try to solve my problem?

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to do. A perfectly reasonable answer would be `alert("i=2 j=1\r\ni=3 j=2\r\ni=1 j=3\r\ni=2 j=1\r\ni=3 j=2\r\ni=1 j=3")`. Does that help you "get what you want"?

Comment: no, i want 2 and 1 to be printed simultaneously afterwards 3,2 followed by 1,3

Comment: Ok, `alert("i=2 j=1")`, `alert("i=3 j=2")`, `alert("i=1 j=3")`... seriously, if you can't even describe your problem in a better way, how can we possibly help you?

Comment: The reason you are getting downvoted is because your question makes little sense and there appears to be no reason for you to do this. Give us some context. You say 'and so on' but what does that mean? Does that mean you want it to get permanantly stuck in an infinite loop? We can make that happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's seems to an easy problem : you just have to count 1 by 1 with 2 variables (i and j), the differences is than you don't start at 1 for both.

You need to increment j and i at the same time.

```
// this for not making infinite loop
var nb_loop=0;
var max_loop=10; 
var j=0;
for (var i=2; i<=3 ; i++){
  nb_loop++;
  j++;
  console.log("i="+i+", j="+j); // or alert if you want
  if (j>=3)
    j=0;
  if (i>=3)
    i=0;
  if (nb_loop>max_loop)
    break; 
}
```

Note: a while loop may be better than the "for"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if u need to use this, i reproduce your output (**see console**)

```
var c=1,
    j = 2,
    i = 0,
    x = 2; // this a limit for loop to prevent infinite loop

for (c; c<=3; c++){
    if(c == 1){
        i = 2;
    }else if(c == 2){
        i = 3;
    }else{
        i = 1;
    }

    //alert("i="+i+" j="+c); uncomment to see alert
    console.log("i="+i+" j="+c);

    //you can change this condition to stop the loop where you need
    if(c==3 && x != 0){
        c = 1;
        x--;
    }
}
```

see this example, maybe can help:
http://jsfiddle.net/pvMby/1/